# Why do VSCode's Python Language Server concatenate paths?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm struggling with VSCode when I try to navigate my project's files. I think the Python Language Server is also involved here.

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5olZ.png)

It's like the paths concatenate themselves for some reason.

I tried uninstalling VSCode and reinstalling it but it didn't work.

The settings JSON contains the following:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "bin/python"
}
```

The python interpreter is located in a relative path which is `/home/esteban/Desktop/( - ) 2034 Programación I - A. Navarro (R)/Repositorio GitLab/seismology/api/bin/python`

The directory is linked to the real path: `/media/esteban/Esteban/_UM/3° AÑO/_M A T E R I A S/( - ) 2034 Programación I - A. Navarro (R)/Repositorio GitLab/seismology/api/bin/python`

Comment: What operating system are you using? Was python added to your path?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 19.10. I created a venv environment in /home/esteban/Desktop/( - ) 2034 Programación I - A. Navarro (R)/Repositorio GitLab/seismology/api/bin/python

Comment: Don't use blank spaces in your folder's project name... this will bring you many problems

Comment: I noticed vscode doesn't do so well with vertual environments. That's why I moved to PyCharm

Comment: Which language server were you using, Jedi or Microsoft?

Comment: I guess Microsoft's... It just automatically installs itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I fixed it moving the repository to another folder.

I guess the problem is that VSCode tries to reach the origin of the file. It's not the solution I was looking for but for now, it works.